# File transfers overload php (or apache?)

Tags: php, apache2, fat-free-framework

I am experimenting with smartReadFile.php and HTML5 / tags and I notice, that after several seeking operations the connection just hangs. All other resources of the server are still accessible, except for any other part of the scriptchain (I route the request from index.php and use require_once for SmartReadFile.php - none are available during the hang)

```
<?php


$f3=require('lib/base.php');


$f3->set('DEBUG',3);
if ((float)PCRE_VERSION<7.9)
    trigger_error('PCRE version is out of date');

$f3->config('config.ini');

$f3->set('UI',"ui/");

$f3->route('GET /',
    function($f3) {
        echo View::instance()->render('video.htm');
    }
);

$f3->route('GET /video',
    function($f3) {
        require_once("smartReadFile.php");
        smartReadFile("oceans.mp4","video","video/mp4");
    }
);


$f3->run();
```

Everything starts working again after some time (or if I restart the server). The problem seems to be in php and is probably, but I wasn't able to find a solution. Any help, please? :(

Comment: how big is oceans.mp4? maybe it's a memory issue.

Comment: @ikkez ~21M. If it's a matter of memory, how do i fix it?

Comment: check the memory_limit option in your php.ini file. maybe the script runs faster when you increase that value.